# Как присвоить значение?

Tags: c

У меня в программе есть значение char a = '1'.
Мне нужно чтобы "a" было равно 49.49.
Как мне это сделать?

Comment: Вопрос у вас примерно "у меня есть литр. как сделать из него 49 градусов?" :) в `char` не поместится ни строка, ни число с плавающей точкой. Что вы хотите **на самом деле**? Грубо говоря - зачем вам это нужно? Вы уверены, что нужно именно это?

Comment: Мне нужно ввести номер товара, вывести на экран, какой товар продан и на какую сумму продан этот товар.

Comment: Ну покажите свой код, станет понятнее, что вам советовать :)

Comment: В том то и дело, что кода пока нет и с идеями та же беда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char` - это 1 символ и не больше

если вы хотите записать строку "49.49", то используйте `char*` - указатель на массив `char`, правда надо выделить память под строку, например так:

```
char text[32]; // 32 байта под строку
strcpy(text, "49.49"); // записать в память по адресу text 5 символов "49.49" + 0, который означает конец строки
```

если пишете на c++, то используйте `std::string` для таких вещей

```
std::string text = "49.49";
```

но больше похоже, что вам надо хранить не строку, а число, тогда используйте

```
float value = 49.49;
```